# Merging excel sheets using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a quick script using python and pandas thats supposed to compare two excel sheets, grab the information that i need and create a new file. However when it creates the new file or if i just print it for testing one of the columns is coming back empty depending on where i merge (left of right)

```
    import pandas as pd

base_data = pd.read_excel("UpdatedList.xls") - #this sheet has Names and clock number
today_data = pd.read_excel("LocationUP.xlsx") - #this sheet has Names and where employees are working.

merge_data = base_data[["Names", "Clock Number" ]].merge(today_data[["Names", "Job"]], on="Names", how="right") #this line merges the two and creates a new files using the excel row "Names" as a merging key

# merge_data.to_excel("EmployeeLocationInner.xlsx", index=False)
print(merge_data.to_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't double checked your merge, but rather than sending your merged data to a string, you should use
pd.to_excel()

something like:

```
merge_data.to_excel('merged_data.xlsx', sheet_name='merged')
```

If you need to save multiple sheets, looks the documentation - there are directions there.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

As far as merges, left or right will select what data you want to keep, so check your merge type to make sure you are keeping the data you want.  I would advise trying each type of merge, and seeing what you want.  It might be helpful to learn about different merge types.  Here is a nice reference, or just google sql join types:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

For reference, pd.merge()
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: I had tried all kinds of merging before, if i do left one field comes back empty, if i do right same thing happens but on a different field. Somehow in the merging one of the columns value isnt being passed. The snipper you added does make it simpler to create the excel file but somewhere along the way i am still losing information and i cant figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried a full outer join, how="outer" ?

Comment: Yes i have, and sadly its still not working for me. In the excel sheet the column i'm using as identifier has all values formatted the same way in both sheets so there's no errors due to different formatting.

Comment: Looks like your post was closed - since you're new here I thought I'd just advise that you recreate the post but add in some more details about the merge specifically by adding your data or fake data that can reproduce the problem so that someone can get you a complete answer :)  Best of luck regardless.